# Hibernate hql conversion from sql

Tags: hibernate

Can someone help me correcting the below sql to correct hibernate hql format?

When I ran this query, I am getting this error:**

> ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - 18120 line 2:33: unexpected token: (

```
         em.createQuery("""
               Select create_date from (
               select distinct trunc(create_date) as create_date
               from Count
               order by 1 desc
              )a
             where rownum <=5
            """).getResultList()
```

Comment: When I run the above SQL, I see this values in my result                 06/12/15
06/10/15
06/09/15
06/08/15
06/07/15

Comment: Trying creating `createSQLQuery` instead of `createQuery`

Comment: Arpit, thanks for the suggestion. But javax.persistence.EntityManager is not allowing me to use createSQLQuery(). It only recognizes createQuery(). See if you can help now. and thanks again.

Comment: For `EntityManager` you can use `createNativeQuery`

Comment: Arpit, you rock! it worked. Thanks.